# Make vim indent after private/public/protected methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

My team have agreed to follow the Rails convention guideline regarding private/public/protected methods indenting. Which is: http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#follow-the-coding-conventions

But I haven't found anything on how to make vim-ruby work this way. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you take a look at the indent script used for Ruby?

Comment: Yes, but couldn't tell a way of making it indent after these special keywords.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a few months late, but I was looking for the same feature with vim-ruby and it didn't exist yet. I ended up proposing this and with the help of AndrewRadev we implemented this feature:
https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/pull/177
https://github.com/vim-ruby/vim-ruby/pull/179

With the latest vim-ruby, you can set:

```
let g:ruby_indent_access_modifier_style="indent"
```

in your ~/.vimrc and indentation will work as outlined in the Rails convention guide.